# Is the lagrangian density convex if the lagrangian is convex?

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, classical-mechanics, variational-analysis

Let $L = \dot{q}^T M(q) \dot{q} +  V(q)$, i.e., the lagrangian has a quadratic form and hence is convex w.r.t to the velocities, considering that $V(q)$ plays the role of a constant. And now let the discrete lagrangian, i.e, the lagrangian density be:

$$ L_d(q_{k}, q_{k+1}, h) =   \int_{0}^{h} L(q(t), \dot{q}(t)) \,dt  $$

Where $q_{k} = q(0)$ and $q_{k+1} = q(h)$.
Can we infer any convex property from the discrete lagrangian with respect to any variable input $q_{k}$ or $q_{k+1}$ and if so how can I prove it?

I know that if $L$ is regular then $L_d$ has to be also regular and regularity implies that the determinant of the matrix $\frac{\partial L_d^2}{\partial q_k \partial q_{k+1}}$ is non-singular but that doesn't imply that the Hessian is positive semidefinite and that $L_d$ is convex or even concave right?.

Comment: Please make the integrand more explicit. What is $\dot q$ relative to $q_k,q_{k+1}$ or alternatively, what is $q(t)$?

Comment: Hi, $q(t)$ is a $C²$ curve along $q_k$ and $q_{k+1}$

Comment: But not every such curve will give the same value of the integral. And on the left side there is no mention of that curve.

Comment: Not sure if I understood what you said but on the left side we have that $q_k = q(0)$ and $q_{k+1} = q(h)$

Comment: On the left side you have a function of 3 numbers, or two vectors and one number. On the right side you have an expression that depends on a function. There are infinitely many functions that satisfy the stated condition.

Comment: Yes but for a regular Lagrangian with sufficiently small $h$ there is a unique solution $q$ satisfying $q_{k} = q(0)$ and $q_{k+1} = q(h)$. Ref: section 1.6 of : "Marsden, J.E. and West, M., 2001. Discrete mechanics and variational integrators. Acta Numerica, 10, pp.357-514"

Comment: You mean to say that $q$ is the solution of the Euler-Lagrange equation? Is that not a little too much expectation? If you can solve the Euler-Lagrange equation that easily, why are you concerned with discretizations?

Comment: I'm not from physics neither mathematics. However, I need to learn via neural networks the discrete lagrangian to use further for optimization purposes. Since an optimization with neural networks is not that easy I want to constraint the neural network to be convex with respect to one or both inputs but I don't want to lose physical properties at the same time. I'm concerned about discretization of the action integral because these integrators have shown to have better long term behaviour comparing with traditional integrators like RK4.

Comment: I find that rather improbable that with NN techniques you get better than 2nd order correctness. Fixed-step RK4 is easy to improve using higher-order methods with adaptive step size, with implicit methods one should also get enough stability for the long-term behavior. High-order symplectic integrators (which are implicit) provide almost-conservation of solution invariants.

Comment: Yes but the question is that the dynamics are unknown, i.e, the lagrangian. So, learning it based on trajectories in such a way that it respects energy conservation is important. However, I cannot see anywhere or prove that $L_d(q_k, q_{k+1})$ is convex w.r.t one of it's inputs or both, and consequently optimization of the implicit dicrete euler-lagrange equations is quite erroneous due to highly non-linearity of NN.

Comment: In general, a neural network is some function $y=F(x,W)$ with a huge parameter set $W$ that is optimized over the learning sample. What would you identify as input $x$ and as output $y$ for your task?

Comment: The inputs would be a sequence of 3 positions according to the discrete Euler-Lagrange equations and the parameter set would be optimized in such a way that it respects those equations. So by learning $L_d$ I can then compute the respective derivatives and obtain the DEL. Predictions are made by finding the root of that equation. The DEL here works as an Energy function, so in reality, it's an unsupervided learning problem.